# html to pdf convert in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have created a html page which i want to print and download locally in pdf exactly the same page. but pdf page does not full download it discard the at end 3 to 4 lines. i want to generate multiple pdf page but in a4 size with same styling as html page.

```
(function () {
    var
     form = $('#formpdf, #logo'),
     cache_width = form.width(),
     a3 = [842, 1500]; // for a4 size paper width and height

    $('#create_pdf').on('click', function () {
        $('body').scrollTop(0);
        createPDF();
    });
    //create pdf
    function createPDF() {
        getCanvas().then(function (canvas) {
            var
             img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
             doc = new jsPDF({
                 unit: 'px',
                 format: 'a3'
             });
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 10, 10);
            doc.save('Texas_Transportation.pdf');
            form.width(cache_width);

        });
    }

    // create canvas object
    function getCanvas() {
        form.width(a3[0]*1.3333-80).css('max-width', 'none');
        return html2canvas(form, {
            imageTimeout: 2000,
            removeContainer: false

        });
    }

}());



(function ($) {
    $.fn.html2canvas = function (options) {
        var date = new Date(),
        $message = null,
        timeoutTimer = false,
        timer = date.getTime();
        html2canvas.logging = options && options.logging;
        html2canvas.Preload(this[0], $.extend({
            complete: function (images) {
                var queue = html2canvas.Parse(this[0], images, options),
                $canvas = $(html2canvas.Renderer(queue, options)),
                finishTime = new Date();

                $canvas.css({ position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0 }).appendTo(document.body);
                $canvas.siblings().toggle();

                $(window).click(function () {
                    if (!$canvas.is(':visible')) {
                        $canvas.toggle().siblings().toggle();
                        throwMessage("Canvas Render visible");
                    } else {
                        $canvas.siblings().toggle();
                        $canvas.toggle();
                        throwMessage("Canvas Render hidden");
                    }
                });
                throwMessage('Screenshot created in ' + ((finishTime.getTime() - timer) / 1000) + " seconds<br />", 4000);
            }
        }, options));

        function throwMessage(msg, duration) {
            window.clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
            timeoutTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
                $message.fadeOut(function () {
                    $message.remove();
                });
            }, duration || 2000);
            if ($message)
                $message.remove();
            $message = $('<div ></div>').html(msg).css({
                margin: 0,
                padding: 10,
                background: "#000",
                opacity: 0.7,
                position: "fixed",
                top: 10,
                right: 10,
                fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
                color: '#fff',
                fontSize: 10,
                borderRadius: 10,
                width: 'auto',
                height: 'auto',
                textAlign: 'center',
                textDecoration: 'none',


            }).hide().fadeIn().appendTo('body');
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: then i can solve the issue in this code

Comment: well thanks i want to create a4 size pdf but when pdf created the html page does not fit on one page. and pdf show only first page and other html sections discarded. plz do help

Comment: basically i want the html page must be converted in pdf and it may be generated more than one page no problem. but it does not in current code, i dont know where is the problem, i want a4 size with multiple pages

Answer (score -1):

- htmltocanvas allows you to take a screenshot of the html content and save it as a pdf.

Usage example:-

HTML

```
<div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
    <h4 style="color: #000; ">Hello world!</h4>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
```

Use npm install --save html2canvas to download the library.

- You can use any third party library like jsPDF or pdfmake. These are open source and provide an API to generate PDF from html content.

Comment: By keeping view on my javascript code, please write a correct code snippet for me by which i can make a selectable pdf file from html page. thanks